# MediaElement.js - detect flash fallback

Tags: jquery, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I'm using MediaElement.js to play a video on a page.

I need to run some extra javascript code if the user is browsing on an older browser and Flash is used.  I've search but cannot seem to find a way to detect if MediaElement initialized the Flash fallback option instead of using HTML5 video.

For instance, Firefox 10 initialized the Flash fallback even though this browser technically has support for HTML5 video.  Therefore, modernizer wouldn't work here.  Any help?

Comment: what code are you using? what MEJS version?

Answer (score 0):

When mediaelement.js (MEJS) uses a *flashback* plugin (flash, silverlight, etc.) for browsers that don't support HTML5 video, it adds an element with the selector `.me-plugin`

You could validate if `.me-plugin` exists **and** if its ID contains `flash` to decide whether to run your other scripts or not like :

```
var _isFlash = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video-player', {
        // MEJS options
    });
    var mePlugin = $(".me-plugin");
    _isFlash = mePlugin.length > 0 && (mePlugin.attr("id").indexOf("flash")) ? true : false;
    if (_isFlash) {
        // MEJS is using flash fallback, so do something
        $("#log").append("<span>MEJS is using flash fallback</span>");
    };
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x39dC/)**

If you run the fiddle with IE < 9 or Opera (both use flash fallback), it will write the log container.